# htaccess rewrite traling slash to GET parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this code to rewrite `example.com/kat-something.html` to `example.com/kat.php?kat=something`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)-([^/]*)\.html$        $1.php?kat=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$                      $1.php [QSA]
```

But I want `?kat=` to be `/` so `example.com/kat/something.html` to `example.com/kat.php?kat=something`  so I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/(.*)\.html$               $1.php?kat=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$                      $1.php [QSA]
```

But it's not working. So how can I allow / to be an GET name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$  $1.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer it works with kat.php but I should have been more specific, it should be kat-preisvergleich.php instead kat.php so with hyphen in the php file, is it possible this way?

Comment: ok then try: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$  $1-preisvergleich.php?$1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]`